# Merging multiple rows into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty complex query that pulls some data. The result set looks like this:

```
mon | tue  | wed | thu  | fri | sat  | sun |  dispatch | driver_id | name | phone
 x  |  x   |  x  |  x   |  x  | data |  x  |         1 |         2 | Bob  | 123
 x  | data |  x  |  x   |  x  |  x   |  x  |         1 |         2 | Bob  | 123
 x  |  x   |  x  | data |  x  |  x   |  x  |         1 |         2 | Bob  | 123
```

I am wondering if anyone can help me to merge multiple columns which have the same `dispatch | driver_id | name | phone` into **ONE ROW**

Therefore I will end up with this (All `data` values substituted `x` values):

```
mon | tue  | wed | thu   | fri | sat   | sun |  dispatch | driver_id | name | phone
  x | data | x   | data  | x   | data  | x   |         1 |         2 | Bob  | 123
```

- `Data` Values are different and they are `TEXT`, while `x` values are always represented as `x`
- There will be various `dispatch | driver_id | name | phone` combinations

Comment: so there will be no different records with a different value for tuesday? for the same driver, name and phone?

Comment: @Strawberry, this is correct. I show `x` where there is no data

Comment: I think you are going to need to self join your table 7 times (1 for every day of the week) and then write a where clause that makes sure you get the correct data :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "x" values are NULL, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(mon) AS mon,
  MAX(tue) AS tue,
  MAX(wed) AS wed,
  MAX(thu) AS thu,
  MAX(fri) AS fri,
  MAX(sat) AS sat,
  MAX(sun) AS sun,
  dispatch,
  driver_id,
  name,
  phone
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  dispatch,
  driver_it,
  name,
  phone
```

but if "x" values are the exact string "x" then you shuld use something like this:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN mon!='x' THEN mon END) as mon,
MAX(CASE WHEN tue!='x' THEN tue END) as tue,
...
```

This will work, unless two or more different rows have different values for the same column.